# CSS HSL color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a color order/palette from light to dark with hsl colors using css so it looks like this:
[image]

For example a value between 0-10 is lighter, 10-20 is a bit darker and so on.

```
 var toHsla = function (array) {
    return "hsla(" + array[0] + "," + array[1] + "%," + array[2] + "%," + array[3] + ")";
};

var getFrequenceDistribution = function (data, splitCount) {
    var frequence = [];
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, data);
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, data);
    var step = Math.round(max / splitCount);
    var temp = step;
    var rgba = [0, 100, 25, 0.5];

    for (var i = 0; i < splitCount; i++) {
        frequence.push({from: min, to: temp, color: toHsla(rgba)});

        min = temp + 1;
        temp += step;
        rgba[0] = (rgba[0] + (360 / (splitCount * 2)));
        rgba[1] = (rgba[1] - (100 / (splitCount * 2)));
        rgba[2] = (rgba[2] + (100 / (splitCount * 2)));
        rgba[3] = (rgba[3] + (1 / (splitCount*2)));

    }

    return frequence;
};
```

I was unsure on how to create this, because this is my first hsl color experience.

I have created a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uro4jkm3/).

Comment: can you setup a fiddle for this?

Comment: I updated post with a fiddle demo.

Comment: @bookmarker: I'm kind of confused. What is this `data` array supposed to mean? I can see that you are calculating the steps based on that but I just can't understand why you need to send an array and then calculate min & max instead of just passing the min and max as inputs. Is there any reason? Your answer may have a bearing on the answers.

Comment: Data is a set of values like size, count of something. It may be 100 or 1000. but it split for 5 equal interval. And every interval has a color. For example 1-100 is red.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/uro4jkm3/1/) is not 100% but it might help you with a starting point. I don't have the time right now to complete this. Basically it uses a rgb to hsl conversion function (taken from the web) and then decreases the lightness portion of the colors depending on the no. of splits. A decrease of the lightness value would result in a darkened variant of the base color. But the output still doesn't match the image in question and that's what I don't have the time to fix now.